# SQL multiple column index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2012. What is the difference between indexing a single non clustered non-key column and putting multiple columns and then indexing?

If I have table with

> - EmployeeID
> - DepartmentID
> - LocationID
> - Name
> - Address

If I create a single index on

> - EmployeeID
> - DepartmentID

instead of just

> - EmployeeID

What is the difference? I created `EmployeeID, DepartmentID` index, when I was searching any employee with `DepartmentID = X`, the SQL Management Studio Actual Execution Plan was suggesting that I create an index on `DepartmentID` even though the table had a non clustered index on `EmployeeID, DeparmentID`?

Comment: You may also want to read up on _covering indexes_ [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Indexes, order matters.  You want to have the **biggest** subset first, followed by subsequently smaller subsets thereafter.  So chances are, you will be looking for employees who belong to a certain department more than you will be looking for departments of a specific employee.  Said another way, there are likely more employees per department than there are departments per employee -- or at the very least, the consequence of searching is likely to first group by departments.

So if you change your single index from `EmployeeID+DepartmentID` to `DepartmentID+EmployeeID` you'll likely see that suggestion go away.

More reading: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/02/13/60510.aspx

Comment: You can't generally say this. Oftentimes you want the most selective column first, it very much depends on the workload.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, @usr.  To me "selective" column means the one that is filtered on the most.  "Selected" would say the column that gets returned the most.  If you mean selective like I stated, then how are we not saying the same thing?  If you mean selected, then I disagree and would appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

One difference is with column order.

If you have an index on `(EmployeeID, DepartmentID)` and your query filters only `DepartmentID`, the index will not be used. Indexes work left to right.

The other consideration is space and performance. The wider your index, the longer it will take refresh when an `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `INSERT` is performed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the leading part of an index on multiple columns by itself to search, but not the trailing part.

If you have a single index on EmployeeID, DepartmentID it can be used to search by EmployeeID, or to search on EmployeeID and DepartmentID together, but it can not be used to search on DepartmentID without also specifying an EmployeeID.  This is the same whether or not the index is clustered.

If you want to search separately on DepartmentID or EmployeeID, create two separate indexes.